# Grab data points spread across multiple tables MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables for a "quiz" type application.

**Quizes:**

```
 ID | start_date |quiz_name | type
 -----------------------------------------
 1  | 2017-06-08 | Places   | chooseAndInput
 2  | 2017-06-05 | Things   | input
 3  | 2017-05-31 | Shapes   | chooseOne
```

**Attachments:**

```
 ID  | quiz_id     | image_path  | 
 --------------------------------
 14  |       1     | /img1.jpg   | 
 15  |       1     | /img1-B.jpg | 
 16  |       2     | /img2.jpg   | 
 17  |       3     | /foo.jpg    | 
 18  |       3     | /bar.jpg    |  
 19  |       3     | /baz.jpg    |
```

**Responses:**

```
 ID  | user_id |   quiz   | choice | input
 -------------------------------------------------------
 21  |    681  |    1     |    15  | "lorem Ipsum" 
 22  |    12   |    2     |        | "lorem Ipsum"
 23  |    231  |    2     |        | "lorem Ipsum"
 24  |    33   |    1     |    14  | "Lorem ipsum"
 25  |    43   |    3     |    17  | 
 26  |    123  |    3     |    18  |
```

Quizzes can contain one or more images, and can be one of three types, input only which the user writes a response to the image, choose one where a user chooses between multiple images, or choose one and input where the user does both.

I now need to pull in data from the responses as they come in. I want to provide a few data points: Total Responses, Total # of each choice (for choice quizzes), User Inputs (for inputOnly quizzes), and User Inputs grouped by choice and total # of each choice (for chooseAndInput quizzes).

**How would I go about getting the last dataset (# who picked each choice and the inputs grouped by choice) in the least number of queries.**

Edit: Attempts and why they went wrong. (:campaignID = PHP var for the campaign page I'm on)

```
SELECT * from `Responses` r  join `Attachments` a on a.quiz_id = r.quiz where r.CampaignId = :campaignId"
```

> This gives me all of the responses with their choice and input, however I need the groupings of these choices (x users chose y and here's the inputs grouped by y). So I tried:

```
 SELECT * from `Responses` r  join `Attachments` a on a.quiz_id = r.quiz where r.CampaignId = :campaignId" and r.choice = **choice 1**
```

> Which I was going to repeat for each of the choice options but then I realized I didn't know how to provide those choice options without first querying for them

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Hint: join

Comment: I tried to use a join but I felt like I also needed a grouping to get the "inputs grouped by choice" and I can't figure out how to use a join plus a group by.

Comment: Post your query attempt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with my attempts